# boost asio synchronize posted task

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Let's consider the following situation. I have some master-function that invokes a chain of asynchronous operations - function chain(). In this chain I wan't to receive 10 packets, invoking asynchronous processing of the packets and queueing this operation again.

```
void master
{
    chain(10);
    wait_for_chain_completion();
    // Do some other work only after complition of last processor
}

void chain(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        socket_.async_receive(buffer, [this,n](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            chain (--n);
            boost::asio::post(io_, packet_processor);
        });
    }
}
```

Afterwards I wan't to get execution context back to master function. I think such task can be performed using semaphores but I am not sure such solution is valid in my situation.